# Пустой строковый литерал

Tags: c++

Какое внутреннее представление имеют литералы вида `const char A[]=""` и `const char* B=""` ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

В этих двух определениях

```
const char A[]="";

const char* B="";
```

строковый литерал - это выражение, используемое в правой части от знака =, то есть это `""`. Строковый литерал - это последовательность символов, завершаемая нулем. Поэтому внутренне строковый литерал `""` имеет представление как

```
{ '\0' }
```

то есть содержит один символ `'\0'`

В первом объявлении объявляется массив, который инициализируется этим литералом, то есть элементы массива инициализируются элементами строкового литерала. Так как в данном случае строковый литерал имеет всего лишь один элемент, и размерность массива явно не задана, то размерность массива будет определяться по количеству инициализаторов, то есть по количеству элементов строкового литерала. Следовательно массив `A` имеет тип `conct char [1]` и содержит единственный элемент со значением `'\0'`.

Во втором случае объявляется указатель на строковый литерал, который получает адрес первого символа (то есть символа `'\0'`, так как это  единственный символ строкового литерала).

То есть в конечном итоге в первом случае объявляется константный символьный массив из одного элемента инициализируемого нулем, а во втором случае объявляется указатель на константный объект типа `const char` , который инициализируется адресом строкового литерала `""`, то есть его первого и единственного символа, который расположен в статической области памяти.

Если вы выполните следующую программу

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::wcout << sizeof( "" ) << std::endl;
}
```

то ее вывод на консоль будет равен `1`. То есть "пустой" строковый литерал содержит один элемент равный `'\0'`.

В C++ строковые литералы имеют тип константных символьных массивов. Например, строковый литерал `"Hello"` имеет тип `const char[6]`. При использовании строковых литералов в выражениях за редким исключением таким, как, например, при использовании в операторе `sizeof`, строковые литералы неявно преобразуются в указатели на свои первые элементы.

Answer (score 3):

Строковые литералы - это массивы с нулевым элементом на конце.
По этому представление `""` - это массив из одного элемента, который равен `'\0'`.

```
const char __empty[1] = {'\0'};
```

При этом отличие переменных `A` и `B` в том, что
у `A` тип `const char[1]`, как и у литерала, которым он инициализируется,
а `B` - это указатель с типом `const char*` (который указывает на массив `char[1]`).

Comment: И второй тоже??

Comment: Имхо, есть смысл уточнить, что одинаковые строковые литералы не обязаны храниться в одном и том же месте.

Comment: @Abyx вот именно. Как раз поэтому хорошо бы такую информацию добавить.